# MYSQL is giving strange results while comparing the 0 with varchar field

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

***I KNOW THAT ITS STUPID IDEA TO COMPARE NUMBER WITH VARCHAR FIELD AND I SHOULDN'T COMPARE IT, BUT I JUST WANT TO UNDERSTAND THE REASON.***

I am having table with following schema.

```
Table: user
--------------------
number varchar(24)
```

I am having MyISAM as storage engine.

The number field is containing mixed data i.e. numbers(like '9999999') and strings(like 'signup').

I am trying to run following query.

```
SELECT * FROM user where number=0
```

But its returning all the rows where number field is containing either string value like 'signup' or empty in number field.

While if I run following queries..

```
SELECT * FROM user where number=1 or SELECT * FROM user where number=97654
```

They are not returning any rows as none of the row is having 1 or 97654 value in its number field.

Can someone help me to understand how mysql is comparing 0 with varchar field ?

Comment: You need to add quotes while comparing a varchar, unless you will get undesired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*signup* and *other empty values* are returned because *MySQL implicitly converts the strings into integers*. when the string is invalid or cannot be converted into int, the value is 0 that's why it's returning.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c266/2)

Answer (score 2):

It returns all entries where number is not convertible to a number, or is the string "0". This is because the comparison converts the varchar to an int beforehand, which results in the value 0.

[It is clearly described in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)

For actual comparison you can use below query

```
SELECT * FROM user where CAST(`number` AS SIGNED) = 1
```

Comment: I know that either I need to cast it or use '', but I just want to know the reason why mysql is returning the result other than expected.